# mongodb modifying with express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
Player.findByIdAndUpdate(player, {
    $set: {
        points1: {success: , total: }    // modify needed here
    }
}, function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("UPDATED");
    }
});
```

I want to increase value of points1.success and points1.total. But I don't know the correct syntax of doing it. Please help me

Comment: And `'points1` is a nested object or an array of objects? Which one? We don't know what your documents look like unless you actually show us. Also when you "don't know the syntax", it's usually best to consult the documentation for [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents). Pretty clear examples for either case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *findByIdAndUpdate* is not the best choice in this case (because we don't know original value of points1).

With the *findById* traditional approach, you can increment value like this:

```
Player.findById(player, (err, res) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  res.points1.success++
  res.points1.total++
  res.save(err => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log("UPDATED")
  })
})
```

But for sure, there are other ways to do the same.